# Cannot import image from another project

Tags: typescript, webpack

I got the `Cannot find module` error when trying to import an image from `app` project into `server` project like this:

```
import Logo from "../../../../../app/static/icon.png";
```

Here is my project structure:

```
+ projects
    + app
        + static
            - icon.png
        - webpack
        - tsconfig.json        
    + server
        - tsconfig.json
```

Typescript files are imported correctly.

Comment: Please try this @/app/static/icon.png

Comment: You should not import things outside of the project's root folder. It will screw up your compiled output's paths.